# Call another test step using groovy script test step in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have the `Groovy Script`  test step named `Copying_Bulk_File_To_BulkPayment_Folder`.

```
def rawRequest = context.expand('${SOAP#request}')        
def file1 = new File('C:/Actimize/4.23.0.30/Instances/actimize_server_1/QA/BulkPayment/NACHA/Input/RegularNachaPPD.ACH')    
file1.write (rawRequest)
```

After that I have other groovy that should called it 10 times, but it is not doing as expected, below is the respective code.

```
if( context.loopIndex2 == null )
context.loopIndex2 = 0
if( ++context.loopIndex2 < 10 )
testRunner.gotoStepByName( "Copying_Bulk_File_To_BulkPayment_Folder" )
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to do by `gotoStepByName`?

Comment: to run again this step 10 times. if it was not groovy script but for exapmle of soap request sending transaction by service it is working.

Comment: meitale, please check the solution to see if that helps.

Comment: actually it didnt help... the same thing...

Comment: How did you come to  know? Can you please show full scripts of both steps?

Comment: if( context.loopIndex5 == null )
context.loopIndex5 = 0
if( ++context.loopIndex5 < 1000 )
testRunner.runTestStepByName('Meital')

Comment: I will expect the step - Meital will run 1000 times. i will expect the file exist under the SOAP - will be copy to the folder 1000 times.

Comment: As Rao suggests, it would be helpful to see the wider context of the test.  Can you show the rest of the steps in your test to understand the flow and what you are trying to achieve.  Even if the code above did works you expect, IMHO it looks like to would dump the data from the same request x times.  I suspect what you want is a separate file per SOAP request.  Though, without the wider context, it's hard to understand what you ultimately want to achieve.

Comment: @meitale, would appreciate the details of the issue when you applied the solution. Anyways, request to try the `edit` part of the answer if you have already tried the first part of the solution.

Comment: @meitale, updated the answer. Have you got chance to try the updated one?

Answer (score 1):

I did have similar experience. Either `gotoStepByName` does not seem to work or do not know usage of it correctly.

In order get it to work, please do the following change.

**From:**

```
testRunner.gotoStepByName("Copying_Bulk_File_To_BulkPayment_Folder")
```

**To:**

```
testRunner.runTestStepByName('Copying_Bulk_File_To_BulkPayment_Folder')
```

EDIT: OP mentioned that he still has issue without providing the details. Adding another approach to run the test step.

or try below code instead of `gotoStepByName` statement.

```
def step = context.testCase.testSteps['Copying_Bulk_File_To_BulkPayment_Folder']
step.run(testRunner, context)
```

Comment: In the statement `step.run(testRunner, context)` can you please explain me the significance of passing the `testRunner` and `context` parameters in the function `run`. What else can we pass instead of these parameters? Or Can you please provide some reference for the `run` method? I have been banging my head on the screen for quite some time now but not able to get to the roots of it.

Comment: I don't think there are other options. Any ways, please refer api docs for `com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestStep` - https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/index.html?overview-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 problems in your script.

1) gotoStepByName,
change this to runTestStepByName

2) if( ++context.loopIndex2 < 10 )
Since you want a loop better use a for loop instead of an if condition

```
for(int i=0; i< 10 ; i++ )
```

3) File name is same all the time i.e. RegularNachaPPD.ACH , even if you copy 1000 times you will not see this since the file name is same, So you should bring a logic by which every time the name of the file is different

```
int ok= (new Random().nextInt(100000))
print ok
def FileName='C:/Actimize/4.23.0.30/Instances/actimize_server_1/QA/BulkPayment/NACHA/Input/RegularNachaPPD_' + ok + '.ACH'
```

Below is the code i used and i was able to create 10 files

**TestStepName** :- test

```
if( context.loopIndex2 == null )
context.loopIndex2 = 0
for(int i=0; i< 10 ; i++ )
{
testRunner.runTestStepByName( "Copying_Bulk_File_To_BulkPayment_Folder" )
}
```

**TestStepName** :- Copying_Bulk_File_To_BulkPayment_Folder

```
int ok= (new Random().nextInt(100000))
print ok
def FileName='C:/Actimize/4.23.0.30/Instances/actimize_server_1/QA/BulkPayment/NACHA/Input/RegularNachaPPD_' + ok + '.ACH'

def rawRequest = context.expand('${First Step#request}')        
def file1 = new File(FileName)    
file1.write (rawRequest)
```

where SOAP is the name of another test step.

The above logic creates a random number which is appended in the name RegularNachaPPD

Hope it helps. I was able to create 10 files with above code

[image]